# List all missing Dates between a Start Date and Today()

Tags: google-sheets

[Sample Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I19Z37YvQsV3lOz2DZStW1bA9F8YrNfJu-MQVj-fMmo/edit#gid=0) - *With Intended Results*

I need help in listing all missing dates from a **Google Sheets** column that has a start date up until Today().

Date Range: Attendance!G2:G

Formula in: DashBoard!T1

Below is a partially working formula that displays the first missing date **only**. But I require it to list **all** missing dates.

**Partially Working Formula:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SMALL(IF(COUNTIFS(Attendance!G2:G, "<="&ROW(INDIRECT(MIN(Attendance!G2:G)&":"&MAX(Today()))), Attendance!G2:G, ">="&ROW(INDIRECT(MIN(Attendance!G2:G)&":"&MAX(Today()))))=0, ROW(INDIRECT(MIN(Attendance!G2:G)&":"&MAX(Today())))), ROWS($A$1:A1)))
```

Thanks!
Zatin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=FILTER(WORKDAY.INTL(Attendance!G2,ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,today()-Attendance!G2)),"0000000"),ISNA(MATCH(WORKDAY.INTL(Attendance!G2,ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,today()-Attendance!G2)),"0000000"),Attendance!G2:G,0)))
```

- WORKDAY.INTL to list all dates from start date to today
- MATCH to find all the listed dates above in the given list.
- FILTER(,ISNA()) to find missing dates

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It works as intended and it was something I was able to follow easier. Appreciate it! Good Day

Comment: Hi, I was asked to ignore weekends from being displayed which makes sense. **Weekends are Saturday & Sunday.** I tried removing the "0000000" [weekend] part of WORKDAY.INT formula but then the desired results are not correct as the formula fails to read Today() part and shows future dates too. I then tried specifying the weekends as numeric values 1,2 but it does not work either. I replaced WORKDAY.INT with NETWORKDAYS and then by just WORKDAY functions but both the tries fail. Can someone help me with this please.

Comment: Ok, I changed as said, but now the dates displayed are up until 16-May-2018. The first 2 dates are working days that are missing from the date range up to today() 4-may. But the formula also displays 7-may to 16-may as missing dates. I have the results displayed on the sample sheet and also show the intended results. 
**Modified Formula:**
`=FILTER(WORKDAY.INTL(Attendance!G2,ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,today()-Attendance!G2)),"0000011"),ISNA(MATCH(WORKDAY.INTL(Attendance!G2,ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,today()-Attendance!G2)),"0000011"),Attendance!G2:G,0)))`
Thanks!

Comment: Just to provide the Sample sheet again:
[Click here for Sample Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I19Z37YvQsV3lOz2DZStW1bA9F8YrNfJu-MQVj-fMmo/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 2):

```
=filter(
   arrayformula(Attendance!G2+row(indirect("1:"&today()-Attendance!G2))),
   isna(match(
          arrayformula(Attendance!G2+row(indirect("1:"&today()-Attendance!G2))),
          Attendance!G2:G29,
          0
        ))
 )
```

### Explanation

The main idea is that "list all missing" is formally the result of subtracting the set of existing dates from the set of all possible dates.

To implement the set subtraction (complement) we use a composition of formulas, FILTER + ISNA/MATCH. The first argument to FILTER is the set we are subtracting from, the second argument to MATCH is the subtracted set. The ARRAYFORMULA generates a list of all possible dates between 2 given dates.

The repetition of ARRAYFORMULA is unfortunate, but there is no "let" keyword or equivalent for Google formulas. If anyone knows how to avoid it, I would be grateful for a comment or correction to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for this. It works as intended. The explanation provided helps me in understanding the formula. However, the below solution is something I'm going with for this problem as it's easier for me to follow. 
The reason is, I read on various forums on how demanding the arrayformula is on the processing power. I'm a novice at this stuff and I'm sorry if I sounded like one. Appreciate the help. Cheers!

Comment: Sure. I agree that WORKDAY.INTL() is a more fitting solution than ARRAYFORMULA, even though the latter is more generic and I wouldn't worry so much about processing power on such paltry amounts of data.

Comment: This is informative. I'll keep that in mind for my next requirement. 
Cheers!

Comment: @I'-'I Indeed it turns out my formula works even after removing all ARRAYFORMULAs! I didn't know it, stated so plainly, that "anything inside FILTER acts as if already inside ARRAYFORMULA". It would indeed explain why I could never combine the two to do a loop-inside-loop type of calculation. I've been looking for precise semantics to ARRAYFORMULA but didn't find any so far. Do you know if this type of behavior is documented somewhere?

Comment: @I'-'I Also my comment about the ARRAYFORMULA repetition was not about the ARRAYFORMULA function itself. Instead what I would love to do would be a functional programming style expression, like this: `={let x=Attendance!G2+row(indirect("1:"&today()-Attendance!G2) in filter(x, match(x, Attendance!G2:G, 0))}`. But this is a pipe dream I suppose.

Comment: @I'-'I Here we disagree, spreadsheets were a de facto programming platform from the beginning and I think enabling a functional-style "let x= in ..." would be much more in line with the spirit and philosophy of a spreadsheet than forcing people to do imperative-style app script.